# If dim($W$), $|S|$ are equal and finite, then the elements of $S$ are not linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Given that $V$ is a vector space, $S \subseteq V$ is a subset, and $W \leq V$ is the subspace spanned by the elements of $S$, I'm asked to prove or disprove the statement in the title. I'm simply looking for verification/critique of what I've written below:

This statement is false. Without loss of generality, assume that $S$ has size $n\geq1$. That is, $S=\{s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_n\}$. Because $W$ is spanned by the elements of $S$, we have that $s_1,\cdots,s_n\in W$, and every element of $W$ is a linear combination of $s_1,\cdots,s_n$. The dimension of $W$ is given by the size of a basis for $W$. A basis for $W$ is given by linearly independent elements of $W$ that span $W$. Because every vector in $W$ is a linear combination of $s_1,\cdots s_n$, dim$(W)\leq n$. This implies that, if dim$(W)=|S|=n$, then $s_1,\cdots,s_n$ must be linearly independent, as they are all basis vectors for $W$.

Comment: Your argument is right, but I think you could be more precise in "if $dim(W)=n$, then $s_1,..., s_n$ must be linearly independent".

Comment: @RafaelHolanda Thanks, I added a small clarification at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to prove that the statement is false, it suffices to find a counterexample. Just take $W = \{0\}$ and $S = \emptyset$. Then $|S| = \dim(W) = 0$ but the elements of $S$ are linearly independent...

Comment: Does this work? I'm not sure if $W$ is spanned by the elements of $S$ here, since $S$ is empty. Is 0 a linear combination of, well, nothing? If so, this is great.

Comment: It does work. See [Empty sum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum).

Comment: If you ever have a doubt about what is spanned by the empty set, you should remember the definition of the vector space spanned by $X$: it is the smallest subvector space of $V$ containing $X$. With $X=\emptyset$, this becomes "the smallest subvector space", in other words $\{0\}$