# Suppose $m\geq 1$. If $W$ is a proper subspace of $V$ whenever $|S|=m$, then dim($V$)$>m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Given that $V$ is a vector space, $S \subseteq V$ is a subset, and $W \leq V$ is the subspace spanned by the elements of $S$, I'm asked to prove or disprove the statement in the title. (Note, this is a continuation of this post: [If dim($W$), $|S|$ are equal and finite, then the elements of $S$ are not linearly independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592619/if-dimw-s-are-equal-and-finite-then-the-elements-of-s-are-not-linear/2592725?noredirect=1#comment5353074_2592725))
I have a proof written, but I'm not confident in it, so I'm looking for verification/critique.

This is true.

Assume $W<V$ and $|S|=m$. Then dim$(W)\leq m$ (as explained in the previous post). Then since $W<V$, it is necessarily true that dim$(W)<$ dim$(V)$. Thus, dim$(W)\leq m<$ dim$(V)\Rightarrow$ dim$(V)>m$, as desired.

Comment: Wait... you said it was false and then attempted to prove it.

Comment: Heh, oops. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true, but your proof has many issues. Primarily, if $a\le b$, $a<c$, you cannot conclude $b < c$. For example $1\le 5$, and $1 < 3$, but it's not the case that $3 < 5$.

The correct proof is: Choose a basis of $V$. Suppose for contradiction that $\dim V \le m$, then we can take $S$ to contain the basis of $V$, then throw in extra vectors if necessary to get $|S|=m$. But then the span of $S$ will be all of $V$, since it contains a basis for $V$, so $W$ will not be a proper subspace of $V$, contradicting the assumption. Thus since we've arrived at a contradiction, we must have $\dim V > m$.

Comment: Wow, I made a really careless mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. Are we able to assume without loss of generality that $S$ contains a basis of $V$? Or is that simply the required binary choice for the contradiction argument?

Comment: Well it says in the statement that it's supposed to hold for all sets $S$ of cardinality $m$, so if $\dim V \le m$, then yes we can construct an $S$ of cardinality $m$ containing a basis.